# Evitar recargar las vistas en codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

tengo el siguiente inconveniente tengo un navbar con un menu y cada uno carga una vista con un formulario cada vista pertenece a un controlador distinto y se carga aparte el header y el footer, el tema es que cada vez que hago click me recarga todo (se pone en blanco la parte del navbar y vuelve a cargar) no se puede hacer que las vistas Entradas, salidas y devoluciones   se cargen sin recargar toda esa parte de la  pagina. adjunto una imagen del menu y luego el codigo de los controladores y vistas. Desde ya muchas gracias

[image: Imagen con el menú navbar todo esto esta dentro de una plantilla adminLTE que no se recarga pero cada vez que hago click en el menu navbar se pone en blanco esta parte y carga por ejemplo el menu salida]

//Controlador "creporte" cada metodo llama a una vista estaria mal aquí?

```
<?php
```

/**
 *
 */
class Creporte extends CI_Controller {

```
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('reportesm/mreportes');
    $this->load->view('layout/header');
    $this->load->view('layout/menu');
    $this->load->view('layout/footer');

}
public function index() {

    $this->load->view('reportes/vreport_fech');

}

public function reporfechs() {

    $this->load->view('reportes/vreport_fechs');
}

public function repordev() {

    $this->load->view('reportes/vreport_dev');
}
```

}

?>

// vista vreport_fech. cuando presiono el menu recarga todo la seccion del navbar

```
 <body>

<div class="content-wrapper">
  <div class="page-title">
    <div>
      <h1><i class="fas fa-dolly-flatbed"></i>  Consulta de movimientos x fechas</h1>


    </div>

  </div>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">

      </div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

        <li class="active"><a href="<?php echo base_url('reportes/creporte') ?>">Entradas</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('reportes/creporte/reporfechs') ?>">Salidas</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('reportes/creporte/repordev') ?>">Devoluciones</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>





    <div class="row clearfix ">
       <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="card" style="background-color: #F9F8F5; height: 260px">
           <div class="card-title-w-btn">
            <h4 class="title"><i class=""></i> Ingrese rango de fechas</h4>


         </div>
         <div class="card-body">

        <form  method="POST" action="" name="frm1" id="frm1">





     <div class="col-md-4 " style="display: none;">
                <label class="control-label">area:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="18" name="area" id="area" placeholder="user"  >
              </div>



 <div class="col-md-4 " style="display: none;">
            <label class="control-label">IDarea:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="18" 
                   name="idarea" id="idarea" placeholder="Nombre"  >
            </div>




              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form horizontal">
                  <label class="control-label">Fecha desde:</label>
                  <input name= "Fechadesde" id="Fechadesde" type="date" class="form-control"  placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" title="Por favor ingrese fecha desde">
               </div>
             </div>

                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form horizontal">
                      <label class="control-label">Fecha hasta:</label>
                      <input name= "Fechahasta" id="Fechahasta" type="date"  class="form-control" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" title="Por favor ingrese fecha hasta" >
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

Comment: Nisiquiera entiendo porque cargar los archivos dentro del contructor, no se me hace una buena practica.

Answer (score 0):

Lo logre para que no recarge la pagina cada vez que hago click en el menu del navbar cargo solo el header en la funcion constructora y en los metodos cargo al final las vistas menu y footer, despues de cargar las vista correspondiente a entrada, salida y devolución, Es una cuestion de orden en la carga de las vistas Así quedaría el controlador:

```
<?php
```

/**
 *
 */
class Creporte extends CI_Controller {

```
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('reportesm/mreportes');
    $this->load->view('layout/header');
}
public function index() {

    $this->load->view('reportes/vreport_fech');
    $this->load->view('layout/menu');
    $this->load->view('layout/footer');

}

public function reporfechs() {

    $this->load->view('reportes/vreport_fechs');
    $this->load->view('layout/menu');
    $this->load->view('layout/footer');
    //redirect('reportes/vreport_fechs');
}

public function repordev() {

    $this->load->view('reportes/vreport_dev');
    $this->load->view('layout/menu');
    $this->load->view('layout/footer');
    //redirect('reportes/vreport_dev');
}
```

}